# How can I migrate MySQL database to Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

How can I migrate MySQL database to Memgraph? Do I need to dump the database in some format and then import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tool `mgmigrate` to migrate your running MySQL database into a running Memgraph instance.

The detailed instruction can be found on the documentation page [Migrate MySQL database to Memgraph](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/import-data/migrate/mysql)